# MongoDB & Node : $in with an ObjectId array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get a bunch of records from a collection based on their Ids. This is my function:

```
const getClassesForIDs = (classIDArray) => {
   
    console.log('in model getClassesForIDs');
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
        Class.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {_id:{$in:classIDArray.map(_post => {new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_post)})}}
            },
        ]).exec(function (err, classData) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(classData);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

```
classIdArray = ["6091468e749cd2f796f01efd", "60923c997b4d3205009a981b"]
```

Even though there are records matching these Ids, this function returns an empty array. When I run it in MongoDB compass, it returns the correct record:

```
{
  "_id" : {$in: [ObjectId('6091468e749cd2f796f01efd'), ObjectId('60923c997b4d3205009a981b')]}
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues is in map function, correct this as below,

Remove bracket {} from map function or return the element through `return` keyword when you use {} bracket,

- **First syntax:**

```
classIDArray.map(_post => new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_post))
```

- **Second syntax:**

```
classIDArray.map(_post => { return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_post) })
```